# ngFor finding first and last and total index

Tags: angular

my json is like this
    [{score: 9},{score: 8.5}]

I want to show **first and last** score only. below work well if I have more then 2 objects.

```
<!-- first score -->
<div class=""  *ngFor="let fs of score  ; index as j; first as isFirst">
                    <div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center" *ngIf="isFirst">
                  <div> {{fs.score}}  <---- first Div
                  </div>

<!-- last score -->
<div class="" *ngFor="let ls of score  ; index as i; last as isLast">
                  <div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center"  *ngIf="isLast">
                  <div> {{ls.score}}   <---- last Div
                  </div>
```

if my json has only one object

```
[{score: 9}]
```

it repeat same value in first and last div. which is logical. but I want to avoid repeating it. is there a way to find out total index and then print first and last or any other way

basically want to avoid repeating values in div if there is only one object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the index of your “last”

```
*ngIf=“isLast && i !== 0”
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is far from efficient. No matter the size of the collection, you will iterate all of its elements, despite the fact that you always know what positions in the array are interesting for you. Furthermore, **you perform this twice** with the current template.

Why not simply perform the look up/extraction of those 2 values beforehand? A far better approach IMO would be to simply do something like:

```
interface Foo {}

private _entries: Foo[] = [];
// set-get approach used in order to force the update of the direct references 
// whenever the collection value is set
set entries(v: Foo[])
{
 this._entries = [...v];
 this.updateElements(v);
}
get entries(){return this._entries;}

firstElement: Foo;
lastElement: Foo;

private updateElements(v: Foo[]){
   const length = v.length;
   if(length  === 0){
     this.firstElement = null;
     this.lastElement = null;
   }else{
     this.firstElement = v[0];
     this.lastElement = v[length -  1];
   }
}

<div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center"  *ngIf="firstElement">
   <div> {{firstElement.score}}</div>
</div>
<div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center"  *ngIf="lastElement && lastElement 
 !== firstElement">
   <div> {{lastElement.score}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<!-- first score -->
<div class=""  *ngFor="let fs of score  ; index as j; first as isFirst">
                    <div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center" *ngIf="isFirst">
                  <div> {{fs.score}}  
                  </div>

<!-- last score -->
<div class="" *ngFor="let ls of score  ; index as i; last as isLast">
                  <div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center"  *ngIf="isLast && i!==0">
                  <div> {{ls.score}} 
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will check first and last index of your JSON array then you can use one div only. Pleae try the following code.

```
<div class=""  *ngFor="let fs of score  ; index as i;">
  <div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center" *ngIf="i===0 || i===score.length-1">
         {{fs.score}}
   </div>  
 </div>
```